# Why does this loop break at the first iteration?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm learning C++ and am trying to create a program that iterates from 1 to 100 and discovers all the prime numbers, but basically it stops at the fist iteration in the multiply function.

the

```
cout << "Base: " << base << " To: " << to << " Check: " << check << " tmp: " << tmp << endl;
```

i've added it to check where it stopped

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int multiply(int base, int to, int check, vector<int> &all_numbers) {

    int tmp;

    for(int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {

        tmp = base * i;

        if(tmp != check) {

            cout << "Base: " << base << " To: " << to << " Check: " << check << " tmp: " << tmp << endl;

            if( (tmp % check) == 0 ) {

                if( find( all_numbers.begin(), all_numbers.end(), tmp ) != all_numbers.end() ) {

                    all_numbers.erase( remove( all_numbers.begin(), all_numbers.end(), tmp ), all_numbers.end() );

                }

            }

        }

    }

    return 0;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int top = 100;
    vector<int> primes;

    for(int i = 1; i <= top; i++) {

        primes.push_back(i);

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < top; i++) {

        multiply(1, top, i, primes);

    }

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = primes.begin(); it != primes.end(); ++it) {

        cout << *it << " - ";

    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {` that kind of indexing is rarely considered correct, when working in c++. Indices are zero based, and thus your indexing loops should be so.

Comment: What debuggers were invented for. Btw, you can't modulo-0. Your program is dumping on `if( (tmp % check)` because `check` is zero.

Comment: Use your debugger to step through the program and see what happens.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OP is not indexing. They're iterating numbers 1 through 100.

Comment: @user2079303 I just wanted to point that out. I didn't say it's the reason why _the loop breaks_ actually (thus a comment).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't assume that the comment has anything to do with why the loop breaks. My point is that the comment is irrelevant to the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Why does this loop break at the first iteration?
> ```

You are dividing by zero in:

```
if( (tmp % check) == 0)
```

Consider this way:

```
bool isPrime(int n) {  
   if (n == 1 || n == 2)
      return false;   

   for (int i=2; i <= n/2; i++)
        if((n % i) == 0)
            return false;

   return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int top = 100;
    vector<int> primes;

    for(int i = 1; i < top; i++)
        if (isPrime(i))
             primes.push_back(i);

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = primes.begin(); it != primes.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " - ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 - 5 - 7 - 11 - 13 - 17 - 19 - 23 - 29 - 31 - 37 - 41 - 43 - 47 - 53 - 59 - 61 - 67 - 71 - 73 - 79 - 83 - 89 - 97 -
```